# How do I debug or visualise my ARM USB HID project on Mac

Tags: usb, software, hid

I've been looking around to try and find an application for Mac OS X that I can use to visualise the inputs of an USB HID device, like for example a game controller, or my USB HID STM32F4 Discovery project.

I'm working on a USB HID project in my free time, and would like to see how the inputs are responding on my screen, using the visualisation application.

Simply put, I'm looking for a game controller calibration/visualisation app like found on Windows:

[image]

I've been looking around, and can't find anything. Must be using the wrong search terms in Google. Can anyone recommend something?

Comment: It's my understanding that something like libusb can't grab HID devices on the MAC, unless you make some kind of stub driver to cause OSX to ignore them.  So that is one option.

Another would be to connect the device to another system / virtual machine first.

My personal choice though, for something I'd be developing, would be to output some debug messages over the UART in addition to the normal USB output, and capture that with a USB serial cable or another dev board running a virtual com port example.  The advantage there is that such a debug channel can help you check other issues too.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Gamepad Companion](http://www.carvware.com/), and [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) that let you configure the USB HID to keyboard presses, but they don't have a display like the windows tool. Some of the Xbox HID drivers do, but only for the xbox controllers.

If you just need to see when the buttons on your hid device are pressed, you could use Snes9x, map them to the buttons in the controller setup, and it will display what buttons are pressed when you press them. Doesn't display any axis information.

Edit: `HID Wizard` has a visual setup as well. Again, no axis information. `Dolphin` the gamecube/wii emulator does have axis information, but geared towards a gamecube like controller.

Afaik, there is no random/arbitrary hid profile display like the windows tool.

Comment: Thanks for this, most definitely a step closer to what I want.